# expecting a hash rather than an instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance

I have this error

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)):
  lib/law/production.rb:20:in `clone'
  lib/law/production.rb:20:in `clone_law'
  lib/law/production.rb:11:in `initialize'
  app/controllers/laws_controller.rb:86:in `new'
  app/controllers/laws_controller.rb:86:in `prod_law'
  app/controllers/laws_controller.rb:44:in `create'
```

when using this

```
module Law
    class Production
      attr_accessor :law
      attr_accessor :creator

      def initialize(law,current_user)
        @law = law
        @creator = current_user
        clone_law
      end

      def current__user
        User.find_by_authentication_token(session[:_csrf_token])
      end
      def clone_law
        clone(@law)
      end
end
end
```

where `clone`, `create`, `prod_law` are some methods
I assume `Rails` is expecting a `hash` but I don't understand why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, `clone` is a standard Ruby method. 
Secondly, it expects no arguments at
    all (as error message says), it should be called on the object you want to clone, like this:

```
@law.clone
```